# Odoo - Product category / Domain

Tags: odoo

I'm looking for to filter my products from a category list. I explain.

I have some categories and sub categories. For example :

```
All
    CatA
        SubCatA
            > Product1 associated to SubCatA
            > Product2 associated to SubCatA
            > ...
    CatB
        SubCatB
            > Product7 associated to SubCatB
            > Product8 associated to SubCatB
            > ...
```

Now, i'd like to filter my product list from this categories.

What i know how to do : select SubCatA and display list with "Product1" and "Product2" with "domain [('categ_id', 'in', [categ_id])]" on "product_id" field.

What i don't know how to do : select "All" (for example) and display list with all products. How must i

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `child_of` operator and product.category has parent-child relation child of will produce same result, here some example :

```
<filter string="All Products" name="filter_to_sell" domain="[('categ_id','child_of',1)]"/>
<filter string="Cat A" name="filter_to_sell" domain="[('categ_id','child_of', 2)]"/>
```

Unfortunately, in search view you can not pass Id dynamically so you need to create filter like above and pass id of category or you can use context for getting values.

Bests